# Binding to ViewModels that are displayed using a ContentPresenter and DataTemplates?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, navigation

I am currently using an `ItemsControl` at the top of my application that contains a few buttons, bound to a list of ViewModelBases. These VMs are the pages of my app. When clicked, they set the current page to the appropriate page. A content presenter shows the current view model, and a `DataTemplate` converts it into the correct view.

How can I use Data Binding in these views? Since the view is being created by the ViewModel, doesn't that mean I can't create a new instance of that view model in the view? How can it find the correct instance to bind to? Or, is it automatically bound?

Answer (score 1):

WPF ItemsControls automatically set the DataContext of each Item they render on screen to their corrsponding Item in the underlying collection. This means that, if you have an IEnumerable set as the ItemsSource of an ItemsControl (or any other ItemsControl-derived class, such as ListBox), it will render every item on screen (using any available DataTemplates) and automatically assign the DataContext property of the resulting visual elements to each of the ViewModelBase Items.